# How to repair modules broken after applying patch SUPEE 6788 in magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I have applied latest patch SUPEE 6788 in my magento 1.9.2.1 and found many modules broke.
Is there anyone who done the same and have recovered their broken modules..
Can anyone list detailed steps to follow so as to get thinks working?

Comment: I think in most of cases, if you downloaded this module from connect and even if you paid for that module - its vendor will release compatible version of the module. Now it is the question of time. You also can contact to vendor with this question.

Comment: @zhartaunik: Let say, I had created a custom module in magento in old style but now, since lots of format is changed, how will I come to know that what are the stuffs I need to change so that broken modules starts working